# How can I access to an interface inside setOnItemClickListener method?

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask

I have created an `interface` that has two methods:

```
public interface OnCarListener {

    void onCarCompleted(String c);

    void onCarError(String error);
}
```

And I use this `interface` inside an `AsyncTask` but the problem comes when I try to execute this `AsyncTask` inside the method `setOnItemClickListener` because when I try:

```
new findCar(this).execute();
```

it gives to me an error saying that I'm making reference to:

`android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

instead of:

`com.example.user.project.OnCarListener`.

I had implemented the interface to the `MainActivity` class and if I try to use my `AsyncTask` in `onCreate()` method, it doesn't give to me any error but I don't need to execute it at `onCreate()` method, **I need to execute it inside the method `setOnItemClickListener` of my custom adapter (that it's associated with a `ListView`)**.

I expect my problem can be understand properly, if not, don't doubt ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you implement the interface where you need it. Don't implement the `OnCarListener` in `MainActivity` and do this. This way you can use it anywhere you want

```
new findCar(new OnCarListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCarCompleted(String c)
        {
            // Do your work
        }

        @Override
        public void onCarError(String error)
        {
            // Do your work
        }   
    }).execute();
```

Comment: But if I try this. Should I delete my OnCarListener interface?

Comment: No. Keep it otherwise you won't be able to use this code.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long amount of time until I answer but I was checking about another problem in my program. Your code works but I'm worried about I have a  `synchronized (c) {
                                nameCar = c;
                            }` inside of `onCarCompleted` and it seems that it only works when I execute the method `setOnItemClickListener` two or more times. The first one it doesn't work. Why it could be?

Comment: Why don't you post a new question for that issue and I am sure someone will help you. But do post your code too.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thanks again for all the help provided! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `new findCar(MainActivity.this).execute();`

Comment: I think he needs the reference to `OnCarListener.this`, you see?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
Create new interface in CustomAdapter, which notify 'clickEvent' in 
MainActivity from where you can execute Async.
```

For Example:

```
public class YourCustomAdapter extends AnyAdapter
{
   ClickEventListener listener;     // new interface
   YourCustomAdapter(Context context)
   {
      listener=(ClickEventListener)context;
   }

   // Rest overrided methods
   getView()
   {
     // considering this is your click event
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner)
     {
        listener.buttonClicked();
     }
   }

   // Create Interface OverHere
   public interface ClickEventListener 
   {
       public void buttonClicked();
   }

}

// Implement this interface in MainActivity

public MainActivity extends Activity implements ClickEventListener 
{
  @override
  buttonClicked()
  {
    new findCar(this).execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps you somehow and sorry if I misunderstood your question.